# How to Daisy Chain Eclipse Run Configurations

Tags: eclipse

I use one Eclipse "Run Config" to build/compile my project, one "External Tools Config" to start the server and another final "External Tools Config" to stop the server.

So in the day to day coding, I make a few changes and want to test them out.

So I have call the stop server (2 seconds run time), then the build (30 seconds) and then the start server (30 seconds). I have to do each of these steps individually and manually. I find I can get distracted and forget to do one step or another.

Is there a way to set up an Eclipse Run Config that will run each of those steps in sequence automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm) is what you are looking for. By using the **Launch Group** within the Run Configurations, you can launch multiple applications at the same time or in sequential order.

Comment: Wow thanks, I'd given up on this up thats 100% right! Launch Group wasn't an option in my Eclipse version (Kepler) so I had to go to the marketplace and install the CDT plugin, which appears to be geared around C++ development but at least added the Launch Group run config.

From there I could daisy chain my 3 separate run configs!! Note to get step 2 to wait for step 1 to finish and step 3 to wait for step 3 to finish I had to add the action "Wait until terminated" on step 1 and step2.

Comment: Sounds great! It was really useful for me as well in the past.

Comment: Since Eclipse Oxygen, [launch groups are part of the Eclipse Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/oxygen/noteworthy/#cdt-launch-group). You no longer need to install the CDT launch groups.